# how to filter an id for subcategory in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have create one table with A is `1,2,3` and B is `3,5,5,9,10,10`.

For example, I want to change from this table:

```
NP  A  B C
-- -- -- -----------------------
 1  1  3 why not
 1  1  5 weigh
 1  1  5 hello
 1  1  9 no way
 1  1 10 now or never
 1  1 10 float the boat, captain
 1  1 12 no nelp
 2  2  4 why
 2  2  6 way too much
 2  2 11 help
 3  3  1 not now
 3  3  2 not
 3  3  7 milky way
 3  3  7 this is stupid
 3  3  8 one way
```

To be like this:

```
 A   B  C
--  --  -----------------------
 1   3  why not
     5  weigh
     5  hello
     9  no way
    10  now or never
    10  float the boat, captain
    12  no nelp

 2   4  why
     6  way too much
    11  help

 3   1  not now
     2  not
     7  milky way
     7  this is stupid
     8  one way
```

How to do like that? Anyone know about this?

Comment: Note that generally this kind of job should be done in the client application. A query is merely to provide you with data and it's the presentation level that should care about how to display the results.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/073ec/4

```
select A, B, C
from
( 
  select
     if (A = @last, null, A) as A,
     B, C, (@last := A) 
  from tbl, (select @last := null as x) as vars
) as q
```

Output:

```
|      A |  B |                       C |
-----------------------------------------
|      1 |  3 |                 why not |
| (null) |  5 |                   weigh |
| (null) |  5 |                   hello |
| (null) |  9 |                  no way |
| (null) | 10 |            now or never |
| (null) | 10 | float the boat, captain |
| (null) | 12 |                 no nelp |
|      2 |  4 |                     why |
| (null) |  6 |            way too much |
| (null) | 11 |                    help |
|      3 |  1 |                 not now |
| (null) |  2 |                     not |
| (null) |  7 |               milky way |
| (null) |  7 |          this is stupid |
| (null) |  8 |                 one way |
```

---

@Naim Nsco

There's no need to explicitly declare the variable, I just find the intent(the above code) is more clear if I explicitly declare it in query. Having said that, not declaring variable works too

```
select A, b, c
from
( 
  select
     if (A = @last, null, A) as A,
     B, C, (@last := A) 
  from tbl
) as q
```

See, it works: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/073ec/6

Comment: i have try for another example but the warning appear is >[Error] Script lines: 1-8 --------------------------
 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'if'. 

 More exceptions ... Must declare the scalar variable "@last". What's mean?

Comment: @NaimNsco Not declaring `@last` works too, see my modified answer. Perhaps, MySQL has strict option settings that makes undeclared variable(s) an error? Try to make that option laxer.

Comment: i have try but the problem still the same. Can you see what's wrong with my code?.SELECT a.cat_code,
       a.subcat_code1,
       b.description
FROM
  (SELECT IF (a.cat_code = @last,
              NULL,
              a.cat_code) AS A, a.subcat_code1, b.description, (@last := A)
   FROM ticket a, ticket_category b) AS q

Comment: may i know what's mean @last?.because im using aqua.

Comment: its purpose is to save the last state of the field value. you can rename it to any name

Comment: What is Aqua? What version of MySql are you using?